# iPhone:Got warning when reverse a NSMutablearray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, warnings

I need reverse(sort in descending order) a NSMutablearray.I tried the following code and it works,but got a warning. How could I remove the warning?

```
NSMutablearray *resStatusArray;

[resStatusArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    resStatusArray=[[resStatusArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

> ```
> Warning:Incompitable pointer types assigning to 'NSMutablearray*_strong' from ' NSarray *'
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

user1118321 is correct in the explanation. To fix it, you would create a new mutable array. I suspect this is safer than a cast.

```
resStatusArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[resStatusArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]];
```

Answer (score 4):

The `allObjects` method returns an `NSArray*`, not an `NSMutableArray*`, so the compiler is telling you that your assignment to an `NSMutableArray*` variable is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If your are sure what your are doing, you can use a cast:

```
resStatusArray=(NSMutableArray*_strong)[[resStatusArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

However, I doubt that this is semantically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Set it to be equal to:

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[arrayNameToReverse reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]];
```

This is essentially creating a new array, from the old mutable array, but reversed. The reason it works is because NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray. So, your code to reverse your array would be:

```
resStatusArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[resStatusArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]];
```